# Blackberry - Java - Arabic shows corrupted in the JSON output

Tags: java, json, blackberry

Arabic shows corrupted in the JSON output

I am loading JSON using the BlackBerry development guide code sample: [Parsing a JSON data structure](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21128/Code_sample_Parse_JSON_data_structure_1319797_11.jsp)

It is working fine. But some fields are in Arabic. Those are showing as junk characters.

Ø§Ù„Ø±Ø¦ÙŠØ³ Ø§Ù„ØªÙ†ÙÙŠØ°ÙŠ ÙÙŠ Â«Ø§Ù„Ø§ØªØµØ§Ù„Ø§ØªÂ» Ø§Ù„Ø³Ø¹ÙˆØ¯ÙŠØ©: Ù…ÙÙ‡ÙˆÙ… Ø§Ù„ØªØ´Ø¨Ø¹ [0.0]

[EDIT]

Following is the JSON data I am getting when I call the JSON through Browser. With the same JSON IPhone Application also working. In blackberry do I have to any specific task to show Arabic ?

Note: I am new to blackberry and Java.

{"0":{"ArticleID":171972,"Title":"الخريجي مدير عام الصوامع لـ «الشرق الأوسط»: المخزون يبلغ 2.5 مليون طن ويكفي استهلاك عام","ArticleText":null,"Summary":" ","Source":"","ArticleSource":"","PostedDate":"8/10/2010","SummaryIsNull":"true","Index":0,"AssociatedImageID":979,"HasAssociatedImage":"true","TitleLength":87,"Priority":0,"ArticleLink":null,"MoreArticlesCount":396,"CommentsCount":0},"1":{"ArticleID":171779,"Title":"العضو المنتدب لقطاع التجزئة في صافولا قشقري لـ «عكاظ»: لا نحتكر تجارة التجزئة ونتفهم احتياجات المستهلك","ArticleText":null,"Summary":" ","Source":"","ArticleSource":"","PostedDate":"8/9/2010","SummaryIsNull":"true","Index":1,"AssociatedImageID":977,"HasAssociatedImage":"true","TitleLength":102,"Priority":0,"ArticleLink":null,"MoreArticlesCount":396,"CommentsCount":0},"2":{"ArticleID":171640,"Title":"كريم محمود نائب رئيس المجموعة المصرفية الاستثمارية لدى البنك لـ \"الخليج\": سيولة \"المشرق\" تؤهله للاستفادة من توقعات النمو ","ArticleText":null,"Summary":" ","Source":"","ArticleSource":"","PostedDate":"8/8/2010","SummaryIsNull":"true","Index":2,"AssociatedImageID":975,"HasAssociatedImage":"true","TitleLength":121,"Priority":0,"ArticleLink":null,"MoreArticlesCount":396,"CommentsCount":0},"3":{"ArticleID":171371,"Title":"المهزع عن مهمة «بنك الدوحة»: نحن نافذة لقطر... ولم نأت للمنافسة ","ArticleText":null,"Summary":" ","Source":"","ArticleSource":"","PostedDate":"8/5/2010","SummaryIsNull":"true","Index":3,"AssociatedImageID":974,"HasAssociatedImage":"true","TitleLength":64,"Priority":0,"ArticleLink":null,"MoreArticlesCount":396,"CommentsCount":0}}

Comment: The link does not work for me (410), could you post a short sample of your code?

Comment: Regarding "are showing as junk": how are you displaying that value?

Comment: I have updated the link . I am using a LabelField to show the output. When I directly write Arabic to that LabelField , it is working.

Comment: Asked (exact duplicate) and answered on the BlackBerry support forum:http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Arabic-shows-corrupted-in-the-JSON-output/m-p/781443

Comment: But I have't got any solution from there other than an advice to learn charactor encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSON I encode Arabic text in \uxxxx format.And it is working.

Comment: If you can't change the server level code please use the following link for client side solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000019/blockingsenderdestination-sendreceive-utf-8-issue

Answer (score 1):

Arabic is one of the most complicated l10n cases.

1. It requires unicode (like all non-Latin languages)
2. it is right-to-left (like Hebrew and Yiddish)
3. Each letter has several variations (separated, start, end, middle)

I think that in your case it is encoding problem on one of the sides: either the sending side (server) corrupts the characters because does not say that they are UTF-8 or your blackberry device does not support Arabic. But if you fix this problem you will probably meet #2 and #3, so be strong! Good luck.

Comment: Sending/Server side is working fine and when I chek the output in browser and i got correct data. Now I will check for the next option (blackberry support for Arabic).

Comment: It means that your client side contains problem. It may be a bug in your code that reads stream. You have to specify UTF-8 when you are creating reader or string (depends on your code.) Other possibility is that your BB just does not support Arabic. Try to go to some Arabic web site. Do you see Arabic letters? Is it rendered correctly  (right-to-left)?

Comment: Thanks Alex for your answers. I got one server side and one client side solution. Server side solution was to encode arabic in \uxxxx format and client side solution was as follows. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000019/blockingsenderdestination-sendreceive-utf-8-issue